# Does the continuity of $f \oplus g$ implies the continuity of $f$ and $g$?

Tags: real-analysis

> (Analysis 2 by Tao, Exercise 2.2.6) Let $R^m$ and $R^n$ be Euclidean spaces. If $f : X \to R^m$ and $g : X \to R^n$ are continuous functions, show that $f \oplus g : X \to R^{m+n}$ is also continuous, where we have identified $R^m \times R^n$ with $R^{m+n}$ in the obvious manner. Is the converse statement true?

We know that $f(x) = (f_1(x), ... ,f_m(x)) = f_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus f_m (x)$. The continuity of $f$ implies the continuity of $f_j$ for all $j = 1, 2, ... , m$. We have also a similar implication for $g$. Therefore, for every $(x_k)$ converging to $x$,
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} f \oplus g (x_k) = \lim_{k \to \infty}f_1\oplus \cdots \oplus f_m \oplus g_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus g_n(x_k) = f \oplus g(x). $$

I am confusing with the converse statement. I think that in this case,
$$f \oplus g (x_n) = ((f\oplus g)_1(x_n), \dots, (f \oplus g)_{n+m}(x_n)). $$
I am not sure if this is correct. Also, I don't know how to prove or disprove the continuity of $f$ and $g$. I would appreciate if you give some help.

Comment: just to be sure, is it that $f\oplus g(x):=(f_1(x),\ldots, f_m(x),g_1(x),\ldots,g_n(x))$? If so, then continuity of the function $f\oplus g$  implies continuity of each $f_j$ and each $g_i$, thus $f$ and $g$ are continuous  -for the same reason that, as you mentioned, $f$ implies continuity of each $f_j$-  , right?

Comment: I think so, but I am not sure if we can write what you mentions if we do not know the rank of $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define two maps $\pi_{1}:\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $\pi_{2}:\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ where $\pi_{1}$ projects onto the first $m$ coordinates and $\pi_{2}$ projects onto the last $n$ coordinates. In other words, if $\bar{x}=(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{m}, x_{m+1}, \ldots, x_{m+n})$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$, then $\pi_{1}(\bar{x})=(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{m})$ and $\pi_2(\bar{x})=(x_{m+1}, \ldots, x_{m+n})$. It is an easy exercise to check that both maps are continuous.

Now $f=\pi_{1}\circ (f\oplus g)$ and $g=\pi_{2}\circ (f\oplus g)$. So if $f\oplus g$ is continuous then $f$ and $g$ are continuous since compositions of continuous functions are continuous.